# Is there a name to this stochastic process?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

My question concerns the following stochastic process $Y(t)$:

$$ dY(t) = \mu Y(t) \,dt + \sigma \,dB(t), $$

where $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion, $\mu$ and $\sigma>0$ are some constants. It is neither the usual Brownian motion with drift nor the geometric Brownian motion. Is there a name to this process and are there any references that mention its properties (its solution, moments, etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: maybe looks like a version of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process: http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/391/Lecture12.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I initially thought it looked like the [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) - with suitable parameters, however this is not the case.

Though the solution looks like we can follow a similar process
$$
dY_t = \mu Y_tdt + \sigma dW_t
$$
multiply by $\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}$ then we have
$$
d(Y_t\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}) = \sigma\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t} dW_t
$$
where using Ito we can see that 
$$
d(Y_t\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}) = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}Y_t\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t} dt +\frac{\partial }{\partial Y_t}Y_t\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}  dY_t = -\mu Y_t\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}dt + \mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}dY_t
$$
so we can now integrate as follows
$$
Y_t\mathrm{e}^{-\mu t} = Y_0 + \int_0^t \sigma\mathrm{e}^{-\mu s} dW_s
$$
or
$$
Y_t = Y_0\mathrm{e}^{\mu t} + \int_0^t \sigma \mathrm{e}^{-\mu(s-t)}dW_s
$$
Which can be solved.